# scan COM port Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, serial-port

I am looking for the function that let me scan serial COM ?
I would like to create a batch file that ouput me the serial COM available.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The MODE command without any arguments provides information about available devices, including COM ports. You can quickly filter the output to see what ports are available by piping the output to FINDSTR.

```
mode | findstr "COM[0-9]:"
```

You can parse the output using FOR /F. It is possible the TOKENS option may have to change depending on your language. This works for English.

```
for /f "tokens=4" %%A in ('mode^|findstr "COM[0-9]:"') do echo %%A
```

Comment: Funny, I've understood the question totally differently. To me, they seemed to want to read data *from* a COM port (or *the* COM port, as they put it; perhaps they've got just one available).

Comment: @AndriyM - I struggled with how to interpret the question, and you can see how I eventually interpreted it. But your interpretation may be correct.

Answer (score 0):

with a litle correctio to support COM numbers bigger than 9:

`for /f "tokens=4" %%A in ('mode^|findstr "COM[0-9]*:"') do echo %%A`

the * repeats the 0-9 pattern